# python feature importance bar chart

Tags: python

I have created my feature importance bar charts with the following code. My question is how to label "Feature #" as the column name rather than feature 0, feature 1, etc. the first picture is what i made, the second picture is how i need it to look.

```
for i,v in enumerate(importance):
print('Feature: %0d, Score: %.5f' % (i,v))
plt.bar([x for x in range(len(importance))], importance)
plt.show()
```

[my created feature selection bar chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCIMT.png)

[how I want it to look image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTwEr.png)

Comment: Please, format your code better and clarify that you're using `matplotlib`, as this isn't the only plotting tool for python

Comment: @Buzz my apologies, as the code seems formatted fine to me and it works. I also assumed that using "plt" made it aware that I was using matplotlib. do you have any advice for my question? thank you.

Comment: The `print` should be indented. Yes, of course `plt` make one think you're using matplotlib, but I could name any other plotting object with the same name. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set_xtickslabel` method in order to specify the horizontal legend. In your case, something like

```
ax1 = plt.subplot()
plt.bar([x for x in range(len(importance))], importance)
ax1.set_xticklabels([f'Feature {X}' for X in range(len(importance)))
```

Check [here](https://pythonguides.com/matplotlib-bar-chart-labels/) for more info